# Count of all possible numbers constructed from given set of digits up to given length

Tags: c#, algorithm

I'm trying to generate all possible numbers from an int array representing digits for the number.

for an example `arr= new int[]{1,2}` I get the following.

```
1
2
11
21
12
22

count =6.
```

for an example arr= new int[]{1,2,3} i get the following.

1
2
3
11
21
31
12
22
32
13
23
33
111
211
311
121
221
321
131
231
331
112
212
312
122
222
322
132
232
332
113
213
313
123
223
323
133
233
333

count =39.

I'm not really sure if this is the correct number of entries i should be getting specially for bigger size input arrays.

Is there any math formula for this that I'm not aware of? I know n! does not apply for this case.

Here is the code that I wrote to calculate all possible combinations

```
class HelloWorld {
static void Main() {
    var output =  GenerateAllCombinations(new int[] {1,2,3});
    foreach(var o in output )
    {
     Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
     Console.WriteLine(output.Count);
}

public static HashSet<string> GenerateAllCombinations(int[]  nums){
    //convert int array to string array
    var strNums=nums.Select(x =>x.ToString()).ToArray();

    var cach = new HashSet<string>(strNums);       
    var output = new HashSet<string>(strNums);

       for(int u=1;u<strNums.Length;u++)
     {
            var temp = new HashSet<string>(); 
         for(int i=0;i<strNums.Length;i++)
         {
                 foreach(var h  in cach )
                 {
                     temp.Add(h+strNums[i]);
                 }
         }
         cach=new HashSet<string>(temp);
         output.UnionWith(temp);
       }
         
    return output;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `n` distinct digits,

1. Count of single digit numbers = `n`
2. Count of 2 digit numbers = `n^2`
3. Count of 3 digit numbers = `n^3`
4. Count of `n` digit numbers = `n^n`

Total distinct numbers = `n` + `n^2` + `n^3` … + `n^n` = `n * ((n^n) - 1) / (n-1)` (using the simple geometric progression summation.

Edit: As per @[AlexeiLevenkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/477420/alexei-levenkov)'s suggestion, if `0` is included in the digits, there are two cases:

1. If sequence evaluation is done as strings, the answer stays the same
2. If sequence evaluation is done as numbers, the answer becomes `n^n`

Comment: thanx alot it seams like i'm on the right track  , 3+3ˆ2+3ˆ3 => 3+9+27 = 39,

Comment: Side note: if 0 digit is included and the sequences are evaluated as a *number* the total result is n^n (as all smaller numbers included into sequences like "000126")

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov good point, I'll update the answer